# Visual Studio corrupts memory when using sockaddr_storage

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Did somebody experienced a memory corruption while using sockaddr_storage in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010? This is the kind of code where I have problems:

```
class Base 
{
 public:
    Base(){a=1};
    int a;
    sockaddr_storage addr;
    int b;
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
 public:
    Derived1() {a=2};
    int c;
}

class Derived2 : public Derived1 
{
 public:
    Derived2() {a=3;};
    int d;
}
```

In Derived2 constructor the offset to 'a' in the object is 4 bytes off and setting 'a' to 3 corrupts memory.

Regards,
Dusan Mudric.

Comment: Please provide a complete, self-contained example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: What exactly makes you think that there was a memory corruption. Can you add the text of that error or message coming from Visual Studio, if any?

Comment: I disassembled the code and checked the memory. Assembly code had different offset for 'a' in Derived2 than in Base. I could see that Derived2 set the value for 'a' at the wrong memory location.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code sample I was unable to reproduce your problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <WinSock2.h>

class Base 
{
public:
    Base(){a=1;}
    int a;
    sockaddr_storage addr;
    int b;
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived1() {a=2;};
    int c;
};

class Derived2 : public Derived1 
{
public:
    Derived2() {a=3;};
    int d;
};

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    Derived2 d;
    std::cout << d.a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If you post a complete code sample which reproduces the problem then we may be able to provide more help.

Comment: Code is too big and I can not post it. Here is disassembled code that clearly shows the compiler error:

Comment: If the code is too big to post then you will need to see a test case which will reproduce the problem. Seeing the disassembly is no use as it does not enable us to solve the problem in C++.

Comment: Here is disassembled code that clearly shows the compiler error. In this example offset is 8 bytes different:                              
43: CDerived1::CDerived1(a) : CBase(a)
45: {
46:     m_eType= eST_ONE;
01AB7A46 C7 80 A8 01 00 00 02 00 00 00 mov         dword ptr [eax+1A8h],2  

32: CDerived2::CDerived2(a)
33: :CDerived1(a) 
37: {
39:  m_eType= eST_TWO; // why is it still eST_ONE after the assignment ?
01BAB29D 8B 45 EC             mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-14h]  
01BAB2A0 C7 80 A0 01 00 00 04 00 00 00 mov         dword ptr [eax+1A0h],4